# Exchange 2010 Database dirty shutdown

Tags: exchange-2010, disaster-recovery

We experienced a power failure, after i bring the server up the Mailbox database is on a dirty shutdown state.

I've ran

`eseutil /r E00`

and got

```
PS E:\BACKUPS_MDB_EXCHANGE\Mailbox Database 1773415643> eseutil /r E00

Extensible Storage Engine Utilities for Microsoft(R) Exchange Server
Version 14.00
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

Initiating RECOVERY mode...
    Logfile base name: E00
            Log files: <current directory>
         System files: <current directory>

Performing soft recovery...
                      Restore Status (% complete)

          0    10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
          |----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
          .........................



Operation terminated with error -567 (JET_errDbTimeTooNew, dbtime on page in advance of the dbtimeBefore in record) afte
r 0.936 seconds.
```

after that i ran `eseutil /ml E00` and got

```
PS E:\BACKUPS_MDB_EXCHANGE\Mailbox Database 1773415643> eseutil /ml E00

Extensible Storage Engine Utilities for Microsoft(R) Exchange Server
Version 14.00
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

Initiating FILE DUMP mode...

Verifying log files...
     Base name: E00

      Log file: E:\BACKUPS_MDB_EXCHANGE\Mailbox Database 1773415643\E000004C9FE.log - OK
      Log file: E:\BACKUPS_MDB_EXCHANGE\Mailbox Database 1773415643\E00.log - OK

No damaged log files were found.

Operation completed successfully in 0.436 seconds.
```

so then i tried to run `eseutil /p 'Mailbox Database'` and after it completed it was still in a `Dirty Shutdown` state.

Here's the output of `eseutil /mh 'Mailbox Database'`

```
PS E:\BACKUPS_MDB_EXCHANGE\Mailbox Database 1773415643> eseutil /mh '.\Mailbox Database 1773415643.edb'

Extensible Storage Engine Utilities for Microsoft(R) Exchange Server
Version 14.00
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

Initiating FILE DUMP mode...
         Database: .\Mailbox Database 1773415643.edb


DATABASE HEADER:
Checksum Information:
Expected Checksum: 0x1683ef3b
  Actual Checksum: 0x1683ef3b

Fields:
        File Type: Database
         Checksum: 0x1683ef3b
   Format ulMagic: 0x89abcdef
   Engine ulMagic: 0x89abcdef
 Format ulVersion: 0x620,17
 Engine ulVersion: 0x620,17
Created ulVersion: 0x620,17
     DB Signature: Create time:11/10/2012 16:34:35 Rand:62691655 Computer:
         cbDbPage: 32768
           dbtime: 511641873 (0x1e7f0911)
            State: Dirty Shutdown
     Log Required: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
    Log Committed: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
   Log Recovering: 0 (0x0)
  GenMax Creation: 00/00/1900 00:00:00
         Shadowed: Yes
       Last Objid: 113713
     Scrub Dbtime: 0 (0x0)
       Scrub Date: 00/00/1900 00:00:00
     Repair Count: 4
      Repair Date: 11/10/2012 16:34:35
 Old Repair Count: 0
  Last Consistent: (0x0,0,0)  00/00/1900 00:00:00
      Last Attach: (0x0,0,0)  11/10/2012 16:34:35
      Last Detach: (0x0,0,0)  00/00/1900 00:00:00
             Dbid: 1
    Log Signature: Create time:00/00/1900 00:00:00 Rand:0 Computer:
       OS Version: (6.0.6002 SP 2 NLS 500100.50100)

Previous Full Backup:
        Log Gen: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
           Mark: (0x0,0,0)
           Mark: 00/00/1900 00:00:00

Previous Incremental Backup:
        Log Gen: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
           Mark: (0x0,0,0)
           Mark: 00/00/1900 00:00:00

Previous Copy Backup:
        Log Gen: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
           Mark: (0x0,0,0)
           Mark: 00/00/1900 00:00:00

Previous Differential Backup:
        Log Gen: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
           Mark: (0x0,0,0)
           Mark: 00/00/1900 00:00:00

Current Full Backup:
        Log Gen: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
           Mark: (0x0,0,0)
           Mark: 00/00/1900 00:00:00

Current Shadow copy backup:
        Log Gen: 0-0 (0x0-0x0)
           Mark: (0x0,0,0)
           Mark: 00/00/1900 00:00:00

     cpgUpgrade55Format: 0
    cpgUpgradeFreePages: 0
cpgUpgradeSpaceMapPages: 0

       ECC Fix Success Count: found (16)
   Last ECC Fix Success Date: 11/10/2012 14:49:50
   Old ECC Fix Success Count: found (16)
         ECC Fix Error Count: none
     Old ECC Fix Error Count: none
    Bad Checksum Error Count: found (678)
Last Bad Checksum Error Date: 11/10/2012 11:55:55
Old bad Checksum Error Count: found (678)

  Last checksum finish Date: 00/00/1900 00:00:00
Current checksum start Date: 00/00/1900 00:00:00
      Current checksum page: 0


Operation completed successfully in 1.107 seconds.
```

It's my first time facing this situation, how can i solve this problem and be able to mount the database again?

Comment: You know what would be the best thing? Open a support case with Microsoft PSS. You'll get the issue resolved but you'll also learn something about the issue and how to resolve it if you encounter it again. If this Exchange server is important to you or your business my advice is not to trifle around with it. Exchange is one of the most complex Microsoft products and it's probably better to work with an engineer who really knows what to do and when to do it to get the database back online.

Comment: +1 for joeqwerty - Much as I might want the rep from giving you an answer here I'm not going to touch this one w/ a 10 foot pole. I sincerely hope you backed-up the database before you attempted to perform any work on it. If you didn't you're probably going to be stuck in a restore from backup scenario after PSS scolds you for not making a backup of the database.

Comment: yeah i backup the DB and logs before attempting anything, I'm just amazed how hard this is being for a simple problem that should be just replaying the logs into the DB.

Comment: It seems like a simple problem on the surface but again, Exchange (and it's databases) are amongst the most complex products Microsoft engineers and if you're not totally sure of what the problem and the resolution is then any effort on your part could make the DB irretrievably broken, leaving you to face the potential loss of all email since the last backup. Again, opening a support case is going to get you back on your feet and it's going to teach you something, which is a win-win for everyone.

Comment: Joe's correct.  Why mess with a q&a site with time delays, the "tennis effect" of lobbing comments back and forth, etc. when you can reach out to MS PSS and get quick help (ok a call back with quick help)?  Let them remote in, see what's going on, and get you running...no need to play the hero.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

1.: Make a copy of the EDB file

2.: Then  run eseutil /P against  working copy of the database and after it finishes without any error message then run eseutil /D

C: Once you are able to mount your database, create new database & move all the mailboxes from repaired EDB to the newly created Database

**Solution 2:**
If above step does not work for you, [Create Dial-Tone Restore](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/dialtone-recovery-exchange-server.php) to get your email flowing again and then you can use third party tool to open corrupt database & restore mailboxes into the dial-tone database.